# Email does not reach external mail server (postfix)

Tags: postfix, email-server, bind

I have a mail server on `mail.domainA.com` which is working absolutely fine if I send email to `name@domainA.com`. I then configured a second domain (domainB.com) in bind9 (same server) to use `mail.domainA.com` as the mailing server. However, when I send email to `someone@domainB.com` I see no logs in POSTFIX, so its like their is no contact with the mail server.

Note: I am using Cloudflare. So even if I expose `mail.domainA.com` my mailing server, still there is nothing in logs, somehow `domainB.com` is not contacting `mail.domainA.com`.

**My bind9 configuration for DomainA:**

```
; MX Record
domainA.com.         IN      MX      10      mail.domainA.com.
; A record for nameserver
@                       IN      A       1.1.1.1
mail                    IN      A       1.1.1.1
domainA.com.         IN      TXT     "v=spf1 a mx ip4:1.1.1.1 ~all"
mail                    IN      TXT     "v=spf1 a mx ip4:1.1.1.1 ~all"
```

**My bind9 configuration for DomainB:**

```
; MX Record
domainB.com.           IN      MX      10      mail.domainA.com.
; A record for nameserver
@                       IN      A       1.1.1.1
mail                    IN      A       1.1.1.1
mail                    IN      TXT     "v=spf1 mx a ip4:1.1.1.1 ~all"
domainB.com.           IN      TXT     "v=spf1 mx a ip4:1.1.1.1 ~all"
```

I also have the same setup on cloudflare.

**My postfix (main.cf) config file:**

```
myhostname = mail.domainA.com
mydomain = domainA.com
myorigin = domainA.com
virtual_alias_domains = domainA.com domainB.com
```

Comment: Did you configure Postfix to be authoritative for domainB.com? If not, that's your problem.

Comment: umm I have add the main.cf config files, I am not sure i am no expert here

Comment: Everything that you've posted obfuscated looks correct as far as it goes, so you probably will need to disclose the real domain names/IP addresses to get any further help. ([Why we ask for real information](https://meta.serverfault.com/q/963/126632))

Answer (score 0):

There was no PTR record for `domainB.com`, as soon as I added the PTR record, i was able to see the connection in logs.

Also I had to expose the `mail.domainA.com` in Cloudflare.